# saltstack jinja error argument of type StrinctUndefined is not iterable

Tags: yaml, jinja2, salt-stack

I working on a saltstack state which should add url to windows environment variables according to host region and environment type. I have defined following pillar file:

```yaml
host: myhost-uat-ln
url_mapping:
 http://test-uat-ln.com:
   environment:
     - UAT
     - STAGE
   region: LN
 http://test-prod-ln.com:
   environment:
     - PROD
   region: LN
 http://test-uat-ny.com:
   environment:
     - UAT
     - STAGE
   region: NY
 http://test-prod-ny.com:
   environment:
     - PROD
   region: NY
```

My state is defined in following way:

```
{% set host = pillar ['host'] | replace('-','_') | lower %}
{% set region = pillar['host'].split('-')[-1] %}
{% set env = pillar['host'].split('-')[-2] %}

{% for url, url_args in salt['pillar.get']('url_mapping', {}).iteritems() %}
  {% for env_arg in  url_args['environment'] %}
    {% if env_arg in env and url_args['region'] == region %}
      Set url {{ url }} for host {{ host }}:
        environ.setenv:
          - name: HOST_URL_MAPPING
          - value: {{ url }}/{{ host }}
          - permanent: HKLM
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```

Problem is when I am trying to execute it via saltstack I am getting:

```
failed: Jinja error: argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable
{% if env_arg in env and url_args['region'] == region %}  <=====================
```

I have checked variables and it looks like all are defined as list. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `env_arg == env|upper` instead of `env_arg in env`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I was overriding host pillar when executing state from command line: myhost_uat_ln that's why it was not working.